# Using TeamCity how can I deploy to an environment then run tests against that environment?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, acceptance-testing

I am struggling to get my head around this!

I wish to have TeamCity deploy our windows service to a particular environment, then a separate project run acceptance tests against that environment.

Currently I have a project that builds then runs unit tests, and finally packages up the deployable elements.

A second project takes the package (artefact dependency) and deploys to the environment.

Now I wish to run acceptance tests against that deployment. The tests are not in the deployable package so I must return to the "build" project... I thought I could use a Snapshot dependency to use the already compiled files (I don't want to checkout/re-compile anything)

However I just get an empty folder on the agent when I hit 'run' on this project.

I must have misunderstood how this works! 
Are there any blog posts to help elucidate this?

The tests are specflow/nunint tests.

Please ask for more info if I have not been clear!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set up the tests as an artifact of the build project, then deploy the tests to the deployment environment.

Then run a separate TeamCity agent on the deployment environment to actually execute the tests on that environment.